# Can heroku background web requests take longer than 30 seconds?

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to extend the flask-base project https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base/tree/master/app which comes with a user model only. I've added the ability to run a background task on redis using rq. I've found https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq which is helpful.

However , despite pushing the task which is a long selenium test to a background task, I'm still getting a server error. Inspecting the logs shows:

```
2018-02-13T16:38:26.784505+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-02-13 16:38:26 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:9)
```

So now I'm wondering : Can heroku background web requests take longer than 30 seconds?

Comment: I remember I had an issue with google maps api, where it also took a bit longer. 30 seconds is the default, but you can extend this in the procfile with `--timeout 120`. Here the timeout will trigger after 120 seconds, full `procfile:web: gunicorn main:app --timeout 120`.

Comment: sorry, does not work